# ASP.NET MVC : deployment process considering users who are working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

When I am going to deploy a new version I always think about users who are working now and may be are in middle of a process, e.g. have saved their request and have been forwarded to the bank site for payment.
In this situation if I deploy the new version, the users' process would be broken and process is not completed. Just like middle of a transaction.

Is there a good practice for this issue?